# Imacross..Save extracted data in existing .csv file

Tags: javascript, imacros

Can any one suggest me if I can store the extracted data in my existing .csv file??

I will have a static table in my .csv file and in that table only one column would be varying always.
And data for that table comes from different webpages. So using imacro i want to autofill my table with the latest value.

And also let me know how will the code look like because I have never used imacro much.!

The column marked with yellow arrow will change rest values will stay static. cells marked with green arrow will get values from one webpage and cells marked with blue arraw would get data from another webpage.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is advanced question. It requires JS Scripting and a lot of coding. Ask for a professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, sorry for replying so late

I am not sure how the code would be for entire table prewritten and just changing the value/updating

But you can try this it will extract the cell values which you require.

Try

```
SET !VAR1 NULL
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=50 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:Cell&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
WAIT SECONDS=2
ADD !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.trim()")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=abc.xls
SET !VAR1 NULL
WAIT SECONDS=3
```